# I cant use OR,AND operators for filtering rows in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Part of dataset

[image]

```
df[df['price'] == (df['price'].min()) | (df['price'].max())]
```

the above code gives empty dataset where it should be dataset with 4 rows

when I did the below code  it worked

```
df1 = df[df['price'] == df['price'].min()]
df2 = df[df['price'] == df['price'].max()]
df3= pd.concat([df1,df2],ignore_index = True)
```

can someone help

Answer (score 0):

You can't do `|` logical or like that, you should try two conditions:

```
df1 = df[(df['price'] == df['price'].min()) | (df['price'] == df['price'].max())]
```

You can also use `eq` for `==` equal sign to get rid of the parenthesis, you can only remove the parenthesis if there is only one expression in each condition, so you could try:

```
df1 = df[df['price'].eq(df['price'].min()) | df['price'].eq(df['price'].max())]
```

Comment: hi.. the above code isn't working. it gives same result

Comment: @VINAYDM I edited my answer, it should works now